# hibernate criteria limits 750 column in select query with DB2

Tags: sql, hibernate, db2

I have an existing j2ee application which works well in SQL Server/Oracle but with DB2 it throws :-

```
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Warning
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlWarning: DB2 SQL Warning: SQLCODE=100, SQLSTATE=02000, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.17.29
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.b(hd.java:215)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.b(hd.java:281)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.b(wo.java:2460)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wo.c(wo.java:2405)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.l(ab.java:408)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:62)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.o.a(o.java:50)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ub.b(ub.java:220)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.sc(xo.java:3526)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.b(xo.java:4489)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.kc(xo.java:807)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.xo.executeUpdate(xo.java:781)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1449)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.remove(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1211)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRemoveAction.execute(CollectionRemoveAction.java:113)
```

I am using Criteria APi with multiple fetch join .

which basically means I cant have more than 750 columns in Criteria generated select part of query. I dont want to do any code/query optimization because that will be huge through out APPLICATION. Does anybody know of any configuration , which can increase the limit of 750 ?

Comment: Which platform of Db2 (Z/os, i-series,  Unix/Windows) ?  For Unix/Windows, Db2 11 has a limit on the number of items in a select-list, and that depends on the pagesize (for 4K pages it is 500, for higher pagesizes it is 1012).  The SQLcode 100 just means "no rows found" and that's not an error. Show your query or prove the query works outside of hibernate.

Comment: If your Db2 server is on Z/OS then there is a limit of 750 or fewer items in the select list.

Comment: If your Db2 server is on i-series, then the limit on number if entries in the select-list is approximately 8000.

Comment: .... I think the better question is, "What in the world are you doing with 750 result columns!?".  It's an incredibly rare case that you're going to need more than 100, if that, and you're bumping 750?  Rows, sure, but columns?  What kind of object structure do you have that hibernate is generating that kind of list?

Comment: Thats a valid question  but I dont have a control here . Its  legacy and not well designed so it keeps on loading dependencies. I didnt find a answer to this and finally doing a  refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

No Solution. Ended up in doing refactoring